# Nullpointerexception java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

First off, I'm an experienced programmer, but have very little familiarity with Java. I have about two years of experience with it, eight years ago.

I'm getting a NullPointerException in the following code:

```
public static void handle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException {

    Response gfexResponse = null;

    try {

        ActionFactory actionFactory = ActionFactory.getInstance();
        String requestURL = request.getRequestURI();
        String actionId = actionFactory.getActionId(requestURL);

        IAction action = actionFactory.createAction(actionId);

        ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(request, 0, actionId);
        gfexResponse = action.execute(event);

    } catch (Exception ex) {        
        gfexResponse = new Response();
        gfexResponse.setError(ex.getMessage());
        gfexResponse.setOutcome(IViewConstants.ERROR);

    } finally {

        if(request.getParameter("loginId") != null){
            request.setAttribute("loginId", request.getParameter("loginId"));
        }

        if(gfexResponse.getMessage()!= null){
            request.setAttribute("message", gfexResponse.getMessage());
        }

        if(gfexResponse.getError()!= null){
            request.setAttribute("error", gfexResponse.getError());
        }

        if (gfexResponse.getContentType() != null) {
            response.setContentType(gfexResponse.getContentType());
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(gfexResponse.getOutputData());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        if(gfexResponse.getOutcome() != null){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(gfexResponse.getOutcome());
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }       
}
```

Here's the StackTrace:

```
[6/18/13 17:10:04:518 GMT] 00000023 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: GfexServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.svl.gfex.handlers.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:44)
    at com.svl.gfex.servlets.GfexServlet.processRequest(GfexServlet.java:43)
    at com.svl.gfex.servlets.GfexServlet.doPost(GfexServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:966)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:907)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:701)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3129)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:238)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:811)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:394)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:152)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:213)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.fireCompletionActions(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:194)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:741)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:863)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1510)
```

The stacktrace points to this line:

```
        if(gfexResponse.getMessage()!= null){  <-------- this line
            request.setAttribute("message", gfexResponse.getMessage());
        }
```

This code was being maintained by an offshore contractor, but the company laid off all the contractors. For my sins, I was given the job of fixing it.

If anyone can help me figure out why I'm getting this error, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Add a check to see if `gfexResponse == null`. Null pointer exceptions in Java are usually very easy to debug, because you're trying to call a method on a null object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error indicates that the `gfexResponse` object itself is `null` (i.e. `action.execute(event)` is returning `null` in the code above, and no exception is being thrown)

Comment: +1 Nice catch about `action.execute(event)` . Your answer is the only one which is telling why `gfexResponse` is `null` ..

Answer (score 4):

Your basic outline is this:

```
public static void handle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException {

    Response gfexResponse = null;

    try {
        //Try to get your gfexResponse
    } catch (Exception ex) {        
        //Provide a default gfexResponse
    } finally {
        //Do some stuff with gfexResponse
    }       
}
```

This is bad practice: you're attempting to use exception handling for flow control. Further, you assume that the method you use to get gfexResponse *will* throw an exception if it fails, which clearly it does not. (Some simple debugging/tracing will reveal this directly.)

What you should be doing is the following:

```
public static void handle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException {

    Response gfexResponse = null;

    try {
        //Try to get your gfexResponse
        //Make sure you got your response object and throw SomeAppropriateException if not
        //Do some stuff with gfexResponse
    } catch (SomeAppropriateException e) {
        //properly handle this case
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //properly handle the general case that something else failed (But you should try to be more specific)
    } finally {
        //remove any resources that might not be properly cleaned up if an exception is thrown.
    }       
}
```

Comment: You're right about this being bad practice, @Nathaniel Ford. Unfortunately, that's the way it was originally coded, and no one in management is going to okay the expenditures to fix all that. This is just a small website, but the original developers handled flow control in the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem lies at the line `gfexResponse = action.execute(event);`

only chance in the below line  to get NPE here is   `gfexResponse`  is null

```
if(gfexResponse.getMessage()!= null){  <-------- this line
```

change it to

```
if(gfexResponse!=null && gfexResponse.getMessage()!= null){  <-------- this line
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, still getting the same exception at the same point.

Comment: You guys nailed it, thanks! I was mistaken about it blowing up at the same point.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `gfexResponse` is getting an actual value from `action.execute(event);` (in the `try {}`)? I'd guess that `action.execute(event);` is returning null.

Comment: I guess I'll have to figure out how to use debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the immediate pain - your `action.execute(event);` call is likely returning `null`.  However, this can be mitigated in several ways:

- Null checking, or
- Turning the `try-catch` block into its own separate method call, to return `Response`.

From there, the `finally` block becomes the main focus of your method, and you can check for null without having to worry about `finally`.